# Erro ao abrir qualquer página PHP no XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

Estou com um problema e não consigo resolver esse erro no meu servidor local, estou utilizando o XAMPP e sempre tento abrir qualquer página com PHP é retornando um "ERRO INTERNO".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só olhando o log do apache, erro 500 é problema de programação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução obrigado! Realmente no log do Apache apontava para a extensão open_SSL comentei no php.ini e resolveu!

Comment: Oi Mateus, se você tiver disposição/tempo para exemplificar seu problema melhor e também a solução que você obteve, facilitará bastante a vida dos próximos :)